# Triggering abbreviation expansion or auto completion automatically from a regular expression match?

Tags: yasnippet, abbrev, automation

With [abbrev mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode), I can define abbreviations that trigger when I type a certain term. For example, typing "yn" would be expanded to "Your Name". For this, "yn" must have been defined as an abbreviation before hand.

What I'm looking for is a setup in which rather than specifying the abbreviation terms explicitly, I can specify a regular expression that when matched gets expanded by the defined instructions.

A simple example would be that everytime I type a website as

```
website_name.org
```

it gets expanded to

```
https://website_name.org
```

I'm specifically looking for a solution that works like abbrev in that I don't have to invoke a command after typing my abbreviation to have it converted.

Comment: Set`abbrev-expand-function` to a function that does what you want, in terms of matching a given regexp?